Invalid spec error with conda-forge when trying any conda install
Trying to install any packages using conda install within my snakemake conda environment gives me this error. I can install any packages successfuly using mamba and specifying conda::bioconda also works, but anything with conda install(or probably specifically conda-forge) leads me to this error. I have an M1 Macbook Air. Is this an issue with my platform? Or conda-forge? Wondering if anyone has run into this. Also, I'm using Miniforge.
Example:
% conda install r::r-tidyverse 

Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - bioconda
 - defaults
 - r
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

InvalidSpec: The package "conda-forge/osx-arm64::python_abi==3.12=4_cp312" is not available for the specified platform

Screenshot of terminal error
I tried manually changing the platform from osx-arm64 to osx-64 to see if that would change the error message. Also tried to uninstall and reinstall conda-forge and also set the priority to lower.

do you get the same error, when using conda as seen here,  within a snakemake rule?

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with snamemake. Can you be a bit more precise about your setup? How to reproduce the error? It seems unclear to me.
